# Why can’t Cordova be called in subdirectory with npm on Windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, quasar-framework

Whether I call `quasar dev -m cordova -t ios -T browser` (which calls Cordova in a subdirectory at the end) or try an npm script like:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "quasar build -m cordova -t ios -T browser",
    "postbuild": "cd src-cordova && cordova run browser"
}
```

I get the following error. (`cd src-cordova && cordova run browser` works if you do it in Git Bash, but not from the npm script.)

```
(node:9964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: No platforms added to
this project. Please use `cordova platform add <platform>`.
    at Object.preProcessOptions (C:\....\cordova-lib\src\cordova\util.js:312:15)
    at C:\....\cordova-lib\src\cordova\run.js:30:32
    at _fulfilled (C:\....\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\....\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\....\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
    at C:\....\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:810:14
    at flush (C:\....\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
(node:9964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error
originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by
rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

I can't find anything about this online and it seems really recent, though I don't know of anything I changed at the time. Since then I made sure I completely reinstalled Node and updated npm, Cordova, Quasar, Vue, git!, everything. Still this error.

And it doesn't seem to be Quasar itself. If I do something like this from a directory above Quasar, it works, except for Cordova's failure:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cd quasar-folder && quasar build -m cordova -t ios -T browser"
}
```

Running `quasar info` nets:

```
Operating System                Windows_NT(10.0.17134) - win32/x64
NodeJs                          8.11.4

Global packages
  NPM                           6.4.0
  yarn                          Not installed
  quasar-cli                    0.17.13
  vue-cli                       3.0.1
  cordova                       8.0.0

Important local packages
  quasar-cli                    0.17.13 
  quasar-framework              0.17.10 
  quasar-extras                 2.0.6   
  vue                           2.5.17  
  vue-router                    3.0.1   
  vuex                          3.0.1   
  electron                      Not installed
  electron-packager             Not installed
  electron-builder              Not installed
  @babel/core                   7.0.0-beta.54   
  webpack                       4.16.5  
  webpack-dev-server            3.1.5   
  workbox-webpack-plugin        3.4.1   
  register-service-worker       1.4.1
```

So what's causing this? Is there a workaround or a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Why, I'm not sure. But this is what worked for me, even though everything was installed, from the Quasar project root:

1. Remove the Cordova folder
   `$ rm -rf src-cordova`
2. Reinstall the mode/Cordova, which should even work when trying to run it.
   `$ quasar dev -m cordova -t ios -T browser`
3. After that, Quasar saw the platform (e.g., `browser`, above) as installed, though Cordova did not, and so it kept trying to download it for dev, and build would fail. So, simply:
   `$ cd src-cordova && cordova add platform browser`

It's possible this was caused by moving the Quasar installation around my system, or something going wrong with an upgrade, I suppose. Regardless, it broke `Vue.nextTick` but would still build and so on. Anyone with more exact ideas here would get my vote and/or the checkmark.